# How to spell check python docstring with emacs?

Tags: python, emacs, spell-checking, docstring

I'd like to run a spell checker on the docstrings of my Python code, if possible from within emacs.

I've found the ispell-check-comments setting which can be used to spell check only comments in code, but I was not able to target only the docstrings which are a fairly python-specific thing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I recommend you to try `flyspell-mode`. You could use something like:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'flyspell-prog-mode)
```

in your Emacs configuration.

Comment: He beat me to it:
http://twitter.com/travisbhartwell/status/10574255696
http://twitter.com/travisbhartwell/status/10574197270

Comment: And if you use elpy: (add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook 'flyspell-prog-mode)